# Python dictionary with objects into dictionary with strings

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got dictionary with objects values and string keys:

```
dict{
'key1': object_1
'key2': object_2
}
```

And I'd like to convert it into:

```
dict{
'key1': str(object_1)
'key2': str(object_2)
}
```

Where str(object_1) is a string representation of object_1. What is the simplest and the most pythonic way of performing this transformation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
dict((k, str(v)) for k, v in d.iteritems())
```

or in Python2.7+:

```
{k: str(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

For more complicated dicts (with tuples of objects as values):

```
dict((k, tuple(str(x) for x in v)) for k, v in d.iteritems())

{k: tuple(str(x) for x in v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: Ok, is there also similar syntax for more nested computations? For example to transform key1 => array(object, object) into key1 => array(string, string)?

Comment: @Dejwi - yes, you can transform the individual values as you wish.

Comment: Dejwi, if you you have only one nested level, just use [str(o) for o in objects] within the code above.

Comment: @eumiro I guess you can also use repr() here.

Answer (score 3):

What eurimo said, or if you'd prefer not to make a copy:

```
for k in d:
   d[k] = str(d[k])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using dictionary comprehensions:

```
{ k : str(v) for k, v in d.iteritems() }
```

The above will work in Python 2.7+, and it will generate the new dictionary using a generator. For Python 3, this will work similarly:

```
{ k : str(v) for k, v in d.items() }
```

Comment: `iteritems` doesn't exist in 3, though, so unless you use `items` (the non-lazy version) the same code won't run under both.

Answer (score 1):

The following Python for loop should solve your problem.

```
for item in d.keys():
   d[item]=str(d[item])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this to achieve it without using any inbuilt methods for dictionary:

x={ z : str(x[z]) for z in x }

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar to your question, but I think my solution is a bit long.

```
new_dict=dict([(item[0],str(item[1])) for item in d.items()])
```

hope this helps